# Is it an acceptable idea to use only one activity with fragments for my whole application

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a Location Based application using google map library. In fact the whole appliction logic is like the google map application, expect that we search, dispay our own data(they have geographic information of course).

You can think of our data as another kind of POIs providered by google.

The `MainActivity` contains the `MapView`, while user can search our data by name or keywords, then we will display these data in the map(Using markers), also user can jump to the `ResutlListActivity` activity to see all the result which are passed through from the `MainActivity`.

Once user click an item in the `ResultActivity`, he will be redirected to the `MainActivity` which will highlight the item (passed from `ResultActivity`).

Also, user can check the detail of the data item in a `DetailActivity`, also user can back to the `MainActivity`, and user can search nearby data in the `DetailActivity`, display the result in the `ResutlListActivity` and `MainActivity`.

As you can see, the `MainActivity` have so many entrypoint, like this:

[image]

What's more, we still have the driver plan feature like google, that's to say there are too many interactive between one activity to another, and I have to keep them synchronous.

When I say "synchronous" I mean that if user click data item "xx" in the `ResultListActivity`, then when he enter the `MainActivity`, I have to update the `MainActivity` to display the item "xx"

The synchronous  job made me going crazy because you must judge each possible situation to decide what kind of data you should display accordingly.

Then I found `Fragment`, and I have an idea: use only one activity in my application which contains all the other UI as fragment, like this:

[image]

In this case, take the "query data" for example, when I get data items from server, I add them to the map, and dispaly them in the `ResultFragment` no matter this fragment is visible or not, when user want to see the result, I only need to set the `ResultFragment` visible and make it at the front of the content view(cover the `MapView`). So does other fragment.

I ownder if this is acceptable?

Comment: "Acceptable" to whom?

Comment: @Rajesh i think he want to known about performance perspective,Same app can be done using more Activity as well.

Comment: @Rajesh:Yes, I want to know 1 is it possible? 2 Is it still own an acceptable performance.

Comment: I would go with 2 activities 1 for Listing/Map and other dedicated for detail. List/Map activity would have a toggle to switch between Map and ResultList fragment or you can just have then in a backstack. The case were you have to send back data from detailactivity to listactivity that can be done simply using activityforresult.

Comment: 1. Is it possible? Yes, it is. 2. Whether it'll have an acceptable performance - it depends. You will have to verify it with a test app.